# Full customization of Qt creator coding style?

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style, qt-creator

Is there a way to **fully** customize the preferred coding style in QT creator?

Here's what I mean by example (I'll directly use just a part from the example code from Qt creator's settings):

```
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex(double re, double im)
        : _re(re), _im(im)
    {}
    double modulus() const
    {
        return sqrt(_re * _re + _im * _im);
    }
private:
    double _re;
    double _im;
};
```

I want this to become:

```
class complex // <- lower latter
{
public:
    complex( double re, double im ) // <- spaces after/before ()
    : // <- new line
         _re( re ), // <- spaces after/before ()
        _im( im ) // <- new line and spaces after/before ()
    {
    } // <- new line
    // <- new line
    double modulus() const
    {
        return sqrt( _re * _re + _im * _im ); // <- spaces after/before ()
    }
// <- new line
private:
    double _re;
    double _im;
};
```

And so on, you get the idea.

Is there some plugin for this or is there some "manual" way to achieve this? A lot of other editors have this option (for example, eclipse and slickedit)

---

**Edit**: Argh, I just saw [this coding style](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Coding_Style) and [these coding conventions](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Coding-Conventions). Does this mean, I can't use my own coding style even for code, that just uses QT?

Also, I know about `Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Style` -> copy and then edit, **but** it's very limited. For example, I can't modify *any* of the things, noted as c++ comments in the example above.

Comment: The references you provide apply when you work on the sources from qt project itself - when you hack on Qt. Using Qt is a different matter.

Comment: @KubaOber - I thought so, but as I didn't find a way to customize the coding style the way I want, I decided that it could be "recommended" for all projects, that use QT and QT creator at all.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [Beautifier](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-beautifier.html) plugin can do that. It is integrated in QtCreator 3.*.*

To enable it go to "Help -> About plugins..." and there check "Beautifier" box in "C++" group.

It uses external tools and can use only these three: [Clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) (part of [llvm/tools](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html)), [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) and [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), so you have to install at least one of them.

After install you may either select a popular style (e.g. K&R, [Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml), [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CppConventions)) or provide your own configuration file. For convenience' sake you may use [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/).

You may also be interested in some [style choices](http://www.sourceformat.com/coding-standard.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Qt Creator allows some degree of customization of the code style. The settings apply to individual projects.

After you've opened a project, go to Projects->YourProject->Code Style. You can copy any of the existing styles and modify them to an extent.

Comment: I already did that, but it's rather limited. I can't change _any_ of the things, I've noted (as c++ comments) in my question. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, it is rather limited, but you seem to mix code style with refactoring. Changing the name of a symbol is refactoring, and creator supports that. Of course you have to manually type in the new name.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about refactoring. I don't want to refactor existing code. Instead, for example, when I create new class with the wizard, I want it to be with my coding style, not with the QT's (with capital letter and others).

Comment: @KirilKirov You type the class name in the wizard, so you're free to type it with lowercase first letter. You're also completely in control of the template files, you can supply your own templates and write your own wizards. Qt Creator is easily extensible. I don't see the problem in this respect.

Comment: @KirilKirov It seems that Qt Creator's code style is mostly about horizontal, not vertical spacing. Empty lines are neither added nor removed. It's true that enforcement of spaces around quotes is not implemented yet - feel free to submit a patch for that, it'd be nice to have.

Comment: I'll do some research about writing my own templates and wizards to see if it's worth or the easier way is just to change these things manually. Thanks for the replies. I'll accept an answer later, when I see what will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not currently possible to fully customise the coding style.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator doesn't allow for that, but you can install [astyle](http://histomatics.de/proasp.php) plugin and [configure it](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) so you will get needed format.

Comment: I'll try that and I'll write here if it worked. Thanks.